# Laggy Hololens App since update to XR SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

Since I updated my Unity3D Hololens 2 project, using MRTK 2.5.1, to also use the XR SDK for holographic remoting, the app has become laggy also when deploying even though the profiler doesn't show much activity.
Is this a known issue that can be updated in some settings?

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more information about your project? Without any specific context, the above information make it is difficult for us to profile your application. It is recommended you follow this guide to optimize the performance of mixed reality apps in Unity: [Performance recommendations for Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/performance-recommendations-for-unity)

In addition, the GitHub issue page of MRTK is an important way for us to collect user feedback, and it currently has no reports on the latest MRTK performance issues. As for XR SDK, because it is a Unity API, we recommend that you submit a new feedback to the Unity product team for a professional suggestion. We always recommend the latest Unity LTS (Long Term Support) stream as the best version to develop MR app, and the current recommendation is to use Unity 2019.4.15f1: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases